# Java - Modifying and Serializing an Object concurrently

Tags: java, serialization

I have few questions related to concurrently Modifying and Serializing a Java Object. (The best approach would have been to try out and see the outcome and build the understanding around it but coming up with concurrent code exactly to try out the below things is a bit tricky)

1. Does Serialization put any kind of lock on the object by default or both Serialization and Modification (calling setter method on the object) can go hand in hand when performed concurrently?
2. Can Serialization have any performance impact (execution runtime) on modification of an object i.e. invocation of setter methods concurrently?
3. If the setter method is invoked when the Serialization is in progress - What value will get Serialized for the field being populated by setter method?

Comment: The best approach is not to try out, it is to synchronize to be safe :-)

Comment: 1. No.  2. No.  3. It will always serialize the value you _don't_ want except on Tuesdays.

Comment: To clarify, are you referring to the _Java_ _[serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)_ functionality, or is the word "serializing" a _threading_ term?

Answer (score 1):

> The best approach would have been to try out and see the outcome

That's almost always true. **But it is wrong here**.

The problem is as follows:

Java as a specification is almost always *exact*. It does not generally write things in terms of: "And when you do this, what happens is undefined". It also rarely engages in: "And when you do this, the compiler / runtime / OS / phase of the moon right now is free to decide to implement it like this, or like this". Contrast to e.g. the C spec where the spec explicitly goes out of its way to indicate that the bit size of a 'word' is actually a choice the implementation can make, i.e. in C the exact point where an `int` overflows (and even *how* it overflows) is not dictated by the spec, so you have no idea.

In contrast to java, where the spec dictates it precisely: A java `int` overflows when you add 1 to `2^31-1`, and it overflows into `-2^31`, because in java `int` is a signed 32-bit 2's complement representation. The spec decrees it. A JVM that doesn't work that way is buggy.

**But that doesn't really apply to concurrency specifically**. Java doesn't exactly use the term 'undefined behaviour', but the selection of behaviours a JVM can have in light of concurrent modification is nebulous enough that it might as well be. Specifically, the spec says that the concept of 'sequencing' **is not guaranteed**. As in, the spec neither states that a JVM must act like sequencing exists, nor that a JVM must necessarily *not* sequence things. It simply states that a JVM may, or may not, it's up to the JVM, and it doesn't have to be fair or consistent in its choice.

In other words, the JVM spec in this area reads, effectively:

*"Any time the JVM needs to decide if a write to one field by one thread is to be visible by another, the JVM will grab its evil coin and flip it. The change is synced to the other thread if the coin comes up heads. Evil coin means that the coin isn't necessarily fair. It might be tails every time this week, then next week it flips heads juuuuust as you're giving that demo to the important customer, and then its like a fair coin next month. Such a JVM, while weird, is not buggy - your code is, if your code's behaviour is dependent on the result of the evil coin"*.

In light of the fact that it works this, way, hopefully it is now obvious why *try it and see* **is a big mistake**. Because during your try it and see phase, the coin might well flip heads every time, thus leading you to draw the *entirely incorrect* conclusion that a JVM reliably flips heads.

### Okay, but, what are you talking about? Where is the evil coin applied?

Specifically it's about the sequencing of field writes. Given:

```
class Test {
  static int a = 1;
  static int b = 10;

  static void modifyThem() {
    a = 2;
    b = 20;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(() -> modifyThem()).start();
    new Thread(() -> printThem()).start();
  }

  static void printThem() {
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
```

This code's behaviour **depends on the outcome of the evil coin flip**. The JVM isn't quite C; there is no undefined behaviour here. But there is *arbitrary* behaviour. The following results are **all** possible. If you file a bug with the OpenJDK team that your JVM is broken because what it emits is apparently random (a different result is produced everytime you run the app), your bug would be closed as 'JVM working as intended':

- 2/20
- 1/20
- 2/10
- 1/10

If longs are involved it gets even crazier (because the JVM reserves the right that you can witness 'sheared' updates, where the top 32 bits have been updated but the bottom 32-bits haven't, or vice versa, but this is incredibly hard to observe because on every 64-bit JVM I'm aware of, it is literally impossible to observe it in action. But the spec still says that a JVM that does shear, even a 64-bit one, is not broken).

On a simple Raspbery pi I'm fairly sure you'd observe 2/20 every single time you ran this. On most modern CPUs you probably observe 1/10 almost all the time. But 1/20 and 2/10 are also possible.

1/20 is a particularly bizarre case: That means the `a = 2;` statement appears to not have run yet, whereas the `b = 20;` statement has. But.. `a = 2;` **is above `b = 20;`** so that seems utterly nuts.

And nevertheless the JVM reserves the right to do that.

The key way to think about it is as follows: The JVM does not *actually* guarantee that things that, to your mind's reconstruction of how a JVM does things, happens *before* another thing happens, are observable by the later thing: **The JVM does not *actually* guarantee that sequencing exists** - things are not guaranteed to run in the exact order you wrote them in your source file!

In other words, it's wrong to say 'evidently, a = 2; has not run yet'. It is right to say: "Thread B is observing a state as it was *before* `a = 2;` has run".

The way to fight the evil coin is also in the JVM specification. Specifically, the [Java Memory Model section: JLS §17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html).

The spec saves you from the evil coin by introducing the notion of establishing 'Happens Before' relationships: A very explicit enumerated list of acts which establish that line X (or, to be precise, bytecode X) is to be considered as 'happens before' bytecode Y. When such a relationship exists, the JVM **guarantees** you that it is not possible for Y to observe state as it was *before* X happens. That doesn't mean the JVM promises that X is 'run' before 'Y' - after all, if Y doesn't actually try to witness anything X did (it doesn't observe at all) the JVM is free to do whatever it wants. It also applies only to fields and such - for example, any attempt you make at trying to observe if some other code has run or not based on how long the CPU needs to do stuff is *not part of the deal* - this principle at the CPU level is the exact cause of the [Spectre security vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)) even (observe things you're not meant to by checking how long things take, not by actually reading data).

So that's how you fight the coin: You establish HBs. The easy ways:

- Natural HB: Within a single thread, any statement A that lexically appears in the code flow before statement B establishes HB(A, B). i.e. if you run `a = 0; a = 5; System.out.println(a);` all in one thread that cannot possibly print 0, obviously.
- thread control: `thread.start()` is HB relative to the first statement inside the thread. Similarly, `thread.yield()` vs. a still actively running thread is HB relative to that thread ending.
- synchronized: Exiting a `synchronized (x)` block is HB relative to any code that enters such a block afterwards.
- volatile: Reads and writes to volatile fields establish HB, though it's not always easy to determine which one is the HB one.

There's more, but those are the highlights. A few important lessons from this:

- **Two+ threads all interacting with the same field is ALWAYS BROKEN, and in UNTESTABLE WAYS, unless either [A] everything is just reading, or [B] it's all protected by HB relationships, which.. you can't test for. Yes, inter-thread communication via fields is incredibly complicated and very error prone. Try to avoid it entirely**. (One easy way to avoid it? Use a database. It has transactions, much simpler).
- Loads of java internal code establishes HBs, which further complicates any attempt to witness the evil coin in action. For example, **on almost all systems, `System.out.println` uses `synchronized()` and therefore establishes HB relative to other threads also doing it. Thus, using sysout statements to print out states in threads so you can see what happens breaks the very thing you are attempting to observe!**

### Why?

Modern CPU design. Here's a weird thing you probably didn't know: Modern CPUs **cannot read memory. At all.** - yes, it has opcodes that write and read to memory but those are emulated. What CPUs can actually only do, is read from their own on-die cache pages, and ask the memory controller to shuttle entire pagefuls (64k usually) of memory between actual main RAM and one of those on-die cache pages ^1. It has a mapping that maintains which chunks (usually 64k in size, called a 'page') of main mem are in which of its limited set of on-die cache pages and will map any read or write op to main memory to a read/write op into its on-die pages with it. If the mapping says that the location that needs to be read or written is in a location that isn't mapped, the CPU:

- Finds the on-die page that is eligible for eviction (generally the one least recently read/written).
- Tells the memory controller to go write the *entire* 64k it contains to the right place in the real main memory of the system, and simultaneously tells it to transfer all data in the entire 64k block that the CPU is interested in over it as it does so.
- The CPU then **goes to sleep for 2000 cycles or something similarly massive** because that's going to take a lot of time.

The problem is, if all CPUs are just zooming along doing their work such that the amount of main mem they touch is sufficiently localized that it's all mapped to on-die cores without any need to involve the memory controller, that's fantastic: No need for that 2000 cycle penalty then. But that also means **every CPU is in its own little universe**, and no write any CPU core does affects any other. The state of main memory after it's all done is kinda random - whatever CPU ended up telling the memory controller to sync its on-die page back to main mem *last*, 'wins'.

If java made you promises about the observability of effects in other threads, then java would have to pay the 2000 cycle penalty after every field write, and **java would be ~2000x slower than it is now**. That's, obviously, ridiculous, so instead java gives you 'ridiculous' rules about evil coins instead. Because that way it doesn't have to do that.

### So what does serializing and concurrency have to do with each other?

Nothing whatsoever. Remember, concurrency **is broken by default** - it only works if you explicitly take painstaking care to ensure every access to a single field from 2+ threads is protected with HB clauses, and serialization doesn't state that it establishes any, therefore, is broken if done in a concurrent environment.

Furthermore, there is no such thing as 'locking an object' in java. At best there's `synchronized (x) {}` but that doesn't really "lock x" - any other thread can do with x what it wants. a `synchronized (x)` statement only interacts with *other* `synchronized (x)` statements. There *is no way in JVM-ese to lock an object in the sense that it freezes any other thread out from attempting to modify that object*.

### Answering your questions

With all that context, the answers are easy:

> 1. Does Serialization put any kind of lock on the object by default

There's no such thing as a 'lock on an object', so trivially then: No it does not.

> or both Serialization and Modification (calling setter method on the object) can go hand in hand when performed concurrently?

No, that will result in evil coin flips. Whilst in theory you can attempt to write code that allows evil coin flips but ends up with the same behaviour regardless of how they land, do not write code like that. At the very least it'll be utterly untestable, not to mention unreadable. Just don't. Hence: "That results in evil coin flips, which means that code is broken, so do not write code like that".

> Can Serialization have any performance impact (execution runtime) on modification of an object i.e. invocation of setter methods concurrently?

Given that any code that serializes while simultaneously calling setters is broken without HBs, the answer is therefore: **Yes**, that has a performance impact, because establishing HBs has a performance impact. (Transfering data from one core to another takes 2000 cycles if not more. Even having one core tell another to cool its jets for a bit (awaiting some lock to clear) takes time: Not just the other core having to freeze for a bit or swap contexts to another job, but the mere act of conveying that info core-to-core takes time. CPUs are really fast and those cores are a few millimeters about. Electrons travel at something like 66% of the speed of light. To cross that millimeter? That's a long time, in CPU cycle terms, actually! Physics laws DEMAND that this has to cost some time!

> If the setter method is invoked when the Serialization is in progress - What value will get Serialized for the field being populated by setter method?

The evil coin flipped and that decides. It's guaranteed to be either the old, or the new value, but a JVM can decide to choose which one depending on the phase of the moon as far as the spec is concerned. And of course, if 'the value' is an object with lots of state, you can of course get a sheared object written (where some of the fields of that object reflect the new state and some of it the old state).

### An important sidenote

Serialization, as in `java.io.Serializable`, is almost always a mistake. It's weird, complicated, not particularly efficient, its format is mostly opaque (it's certainly extremely hard to interact with that data from non-java code), it makes software updates incredibly complicated, it makes for very hard to test codebases (where you e.g. need to maintain newer and older versions of the same class simultaneously somehow, with multiple separate src roots to manage all that).

Instead, use protobuf, JSON, XML, JSONB, YAML, CSV, handrolled formats, or anything else. Something a lot more explicit than java's baked in serialization mechanism. And that's also the opinion of the OpenJDK team itself. They aren't going to immediately deep-six the system (that'd break stuff), but they vocally support the idea that it's.. very tricky to use right and very very *very* rarely the right tool for the job.

---

[1] This is a very long answer, and nevertheless it is quite oversimplified. Most modern CPUs have layers of cache pages, some actually share them, the exact behaviour depends a bit on CPU architecture, CPUs themselves also have pipelines and re-ordering sequencers, and so much more. However, the core lessons in this answer, namely:

- All attempts to have 2 threads interact by read/writing to the same field are to be considered broken by default.
- HB is the only way to unbreak it. That, or avoid having *any* fields interacted with by multiple threads and use message queues or databases instead to do it.
- Behaviour is *effectively* undefined, and not reliably so - you simply **cannot** solve anything (be it ensuring that your code is working correctly, or be it learning more by toying around with these ideas) by 'trying it'.

are correct.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Does Serialization put any kind of lock on the object by default or both Serialization and Modification (calling setter method on the object) can go hand in hand when performed concurrently?

Java Object Serialization does not lock object that it is serializing.  It would be up to the thread that calls the `writeObject` method to ensure that it does this while holding appropriate locks to prevent other threads from mutating the object while it is being serialized.

(Java doesn't have any way to block all other threads' writes to an object ... unless the threads being blocked are cooperating by synchronizing in some way with the blocking thread(s).)

> 2. Can Serialization have any performance impact (execution runtime) on modification of an object i.e. invocation of setter methods concurrently?

Not *per se*.  But if you lock an object to serialize it, that could delay other threads, and potentially have performance concerns.

> 3. If the setter method is invoked when the Serialization is in progress - What value will get Serialized for the field being populated by setter method?

That is not defined.  Basically you are talking about the behavior of code that is not thread-safe.

---

Pino commented:

> The best approach is not to try out, it is to synchronize to be safe :-)

Absolutely correct.  And I will go a step further.  If you do try to serialize and mutate an object at the same time:

- you are highly likely to run into problems at some point<sup>1</sup>,
- they will have unpredictable symptoms, and
- they will be hard to diagnose.

<sup>1 - ... but it is not possible to predict when.  For example, they might only occur under heavy load, or on certain machines, or with certain Java releases.</sup>